# Cannot initialize main application. Element 'MySQLNotifier' was not found. Line2, position 2

Tags: mysql, mysql-notifier

Exception thrown by: Program.Main
I installed **`MySQL 8.0.20`** on windows laptop, It was successfully installed and when I am starting **MySql workbranch** and i am getting this error.

`Cannot initialize main application. Element 'MySQLNotifier' was not found. Line2, position 2`

Comment: What is the MySQL version?  and when does it exception appears? please mention this also.

Answer (score 2):

Appears due to a corrupted configuration file or some dummy MySQL services.
if you are using

> **MySQL Notifier 1.1.8**

in windows then change this notifier to

> **MySQL Notifier 1.1.7**

this helped me with this exception in **windows 10** and `mysql community version`. try this 
if this doesn't help you then [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37112/mysql-notifier-error) might help you regarding this issue.